# Can I travel to Spain on a UK visa? I am a Fillipino

Tags: visas, uk, spain, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipino living in Dubai and I have a two year visa for the UK.  I need to travel to Spain, can I do this using my UK visa ?

Answer (score 6):

UK is not part ot the Schengen area so the UK visa doesn't allow you to visit Spain. You will need a Schengen visa.